# GStreamer hello world program in visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, gstreamer

I m trying to run a simple GStreamer Program (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html) in visual studio 2010.

I have included the library and other header files required .
[image: Executable Directories]
[image: Include Directories]
[image: Library Directories]
[image: Reference Directories]

Now the program compiles but gives me linking errors.

```
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_object_get_type referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_main_loop_run referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_element_set_state referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_print referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_signal_connect_data referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_element_link_many referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_element_link referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_bin_add_many referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_bin_get_type referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_object_unref referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_bus_add_watch referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_pipeline_get_bus referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_pipeline_get_type referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_object_set referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_type_check_instance_cast referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_element_factory_make referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_pipeline_new referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_printerr referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_main_loop_new referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_init referenced in function _main
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_error_free referenced in function "int __cdecl bus_call(struct _GstBus *,struct _GstMessage *,void *)" (?bus_call@@YAHPAU_GstBus@@PAU_GstMessage@@PAX@Z)
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_free referenced in function "int __cdecl bus_call(struct _GstBus *,struct _GstMessage *,void *)" (?bus_call@@YAHPAU_GstBus@@PAU_GstMessage@@PAX@Z)
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_message_parse_error referenced in function "int __cdecl bus_call(struct _GstBus *,struct _GstMessage *,void *)" (?bus_call@@YAHPAU_GstBus@@PAU_GstMessage@@PAX@Z)
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _g_main_loop_quit referenced in function "int __cdecl bus_call(struct _GstBus *,struct _GstMessage *,void *)" (?bus_call@@YAHPAU_GstBus@@PAU_GstMessage@@PAX@Z)
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_pad_link referenced in function "void __cdecl on_pad_added(struct _GstElement *,struct _GstPad *,void *)" (?on_pad_added@@YAXPAU_GstElement@@PAU_GstPad@@PAX@Z)
gstream.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gst_element_get_static_pad referenced in function "void __cdecl on_pad_added(struct _GstElement *,struct _GstPad *,void *)" (?on_pad_added@@YAXPAU_GstElement@@PAU_GstPad@@PAX@Z)
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
C:\Users\vickey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\gstream\Debug\gstream.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 27 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is that I'm missing?

Comment: You're setting up all directories, but are you actually linking against the required .lib files of GStreamer? I would hazard a guess you're forgetting to do so.

Comment: I forgot linking them , I thought defining the correct location of the library will do it for me , but I also needed to specify exactly which  lib i wanted to use. Its working for me now :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Great, glad you solved it.

Comment: By the way, where did you get that list of refs/lib/includes etc.? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: it has been a long time, I suggest you try running their sample codes.